# Adding an element to the end of an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

How do you add an element to the end of an array? I know that there is a method 
   objectAtIndex:
But how do I check that I am at the end of an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `objectAtIndex`, you can just `addObject:`

According to the developer notes:

`addObject:`

Inserts a given object at the end of the array.

`- (void)addObject:(id)anObject`

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple docs: [`[array addObject:obj];`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObject%3a)

What do you mean by:

> how do I check that I am at the end of an array?

Comment: It was my bad, I should not have posted this question, I some how overlooked this method

Comment: You can vote to delete this question then, if you want to.

Comment: I cannot delete this post because it has answers to it

Answer (score 1):

Objects by default go at the end.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: When you use the addObject: method of course.